# How to load a property file in a Jar when the loader util is a different jar

Tags: java, properties

I am using Property Loader utility that has been packaged as a jar(PropLoader.jar) within my project (MyProject.jar). My property file is in a different package within MyProject.jar ie. com.my.project.resources.MyPropertyFile.properties and I am invoking the PropLoader util (main class: PropLoader) which expects a propfile name in input as:

```
PropLoader.loadProperties("/com/my/project/resources/MyPropertyFile.properties")
```

The class file where the above code is in: com.my.project.resources.MyLogic

Internally the utility jar uses getResourcesAsStream.

But this causes a null pointer exception:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the file `MyPropertyFile.properties` bundled as a resource with your .jar?  If not, that is your reason: the loader cannot find the file as it is looking in the .jar for the resource.

Comment: Yes it is. I can load the property file if I place the code in the class com.my.project.resources.MyLogic. But if I send the property file name to the PropLoader.loadProperties() then it is no longer able to locate the file.

Comment: It is possible that `PropLoader` is loaded by a different class loader than you own class.  In that case the resource will be looked up based on the context of PropLoader's class loader.  Is there another method on PropLoader that you can use (e.g. pass a resource stream that you open from your class)?   More on the [subject](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-06/01-qa-0606-load.html)

Comment: You are right. The PropLoader internally uses     this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(propertyFileName). I cannot change this implementation as this is a legacy jar. Is there any way to work around this ?

Comment: IF the PropLoader has a method where you can pass the stream or the content of the file as string, you could use that.  Other than that, you will have to figure out how that class ig being loaded and somehow make it so that it is loaded byt the same classloader ar yours.

Comment: I found another thing, if I use the PropLoader in simple java program then I have no issues, when I use it in an enterprise application and deploy it on my glassfish server, that's when it stops working. Can  you give me any hints on how to work around this?

Comment: Ah, the web server problems...  I'm not an expert in that area, but that is indeed the case I told you about: the PropLoader is loaded by a different class loader than your own class.  I'm not sure how to fix it -- it depends on the setup I think.  Are you bundling the PropLoader's .jar with your .war or does the PropLoader reside in a commmon "libs" directory of the web server?

Comment: What package/jar is PropLoader in?  Where does PropLoader's .jar reside in the webserver when your app is deployed?

Comment: Its being bundled into my .ear under the libs directory, while my code and property file is in a jar outside the libs directory. If it helps, I'm using Netbeans 6.8.

Comment: I have a .ear to deploy on the server. In the ear the structure is
/lib/PropertyLoader.jar
/MyProject.jar

The property file is in MyProject.jar as com.my.project.resources.MyPropertyFile.properties

and the code from where I am delegating the property file to the PropertyLoader is also in MyProject.jar as com.my.project.resources.MyLogic

Comment: If you are using the [org.apache.jcs.utils.props.PropertyLoader](http://commons.apache.org/jcs/apidocs/org/apache/jcs/utils/props/PropertyLoader.html), it has another version of the `loadProperties` method that you can use.  Pass `getClass().getClassLoader()` as the second parameter and it will use your class's classloader, which should find the resource as you expect.  If this fixes your problem, let me know and I'll update my answer with this information

Comment: No this is a custom jar, part of an existing project which I have to use, no options around that. I am using Netbeans 6.8 and was hoping there was someway I could tell it to look for the path maybe?

Comment: If it is a custom project, I cannot help you much.  You need to see if there are any other methods on PropLoader that could work for you (either accepting a path on the disk, a Reader or a Stream).  Alternatively, if you can change PropLoader, you can add a method (like in the apache case) to use your specific classloader

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work absolutely fine when deployed on a different server, or even deployed from withing a different Netbeans workspace!

My workaround for my crummy workspace was to place the property file inside the PropLoader.jar

I also found that the problem with my own workspace was a messed up CLASSPATH. Once I fixed it to reflect my project folder everything worked out fine.